# Excel multiple OR conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have three conditions which independently work but I can't get them to work together. I want it to be FALSE if any of the conditions aren't true.

No duplicates - `=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$51,B2)=1`

Character length bigger than 2 - `LEN($B2)>2`

Character length less than 256 - `LEN($B2)<256`

I tried this combined but it didn't work as expected:

`=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$51,B2)=1, TRUE, IF(LEN($B2)<256, TRUE, IF(LEN($B2)>2, TRUE, FALSE)))`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want `FALSE` if any condition returns false, you need to use `AND` to check if the conditions are true. If then any of the 3 conditions returns false, so does `AND` then:

```
=AND(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$51,B2)=1,LEN($B2)>2,LEN($B2)<256)
```